# How to initialize pointers properly

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, function, pointers

I have the following code that calls the function uint32_pack. This program compiles with no errors in Dev-C++ but does not produce the correct result when 'tag' is an even number.  In Visual Studio the program compiles but produces errors and I'm guessing that these errors are why I don't get the correct output when 'tag' is even. I'm still trying to get my head around pointers and I'm not sure where I went wrong when declaring them. Thanks for your help.

Here is the code where the errors come from:

```
 1  int uint32_pack (uint8_t *fieldnumber, uint32_t value, uint8_t *out);
 2  int main(){
 3  uint32_t initvalue = 2;
 4  int return_rv;  
 5  uint8_t *tag = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
 6  *tag = 38;
 7  uint8_t *tempout= (uint8_t *) malloc(30);
 8  return_rv = uint32_pack (tag, initvalue, tempout);
 9  free(tempout);
10  free(tag);
11  }
```

And the errors from VS as are follows:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type' (on line 7)
error C2065: 'tempout' : undeclared identifier        (on line 8)
warning C4047: 'function' : 'unsigned char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int' (on line 8)
warning C4024: 'uint32_pack' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3 (on line 8) 
error C2065: 'tempout' : undeclared identifier  (on line 9)
warning C4022: 'free' : pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1 (on line 9)
```

Comment: It looks like you might be compiling as C code and since MSVC doesn't support C99 it doesn't allow you to mix declarations and code. Compile it as c++ code (rename to .cpp or use the IIRC `/Tp` flag) and see if that fixes it. If you need help with the uint32_pack function you need to include that in your question.

Comment: Looks like you're right. Why don't you post it as answer?

Comment: @negeo And while you're at it - why, oh why, do you malloc single bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last three errors are consequences of the second, and the second is a consequence of the first.  That only leaves the first and third unexplained.

The first error occurs because you are using C89 and not C++ or C99; you cannot declare variables after code in C89.

Reverse the order of lines 6 and 7 and you should probably be OK.  (I think the third error is also a consequence of the first, too, but that is not definitive.)

Answer (score 1):

There might be a couple of different issues here. Unless you've got a custom header that declares those integers types, `<integer>_t` types are declared in the standard header `stdint.h`. Visual Studio does not ship with this header, so it doesn't know what those types are. You can find implementations of stdint.h if you google it.

If your file has `.c` extension, Visual Studio will compile it as a C file by default. Also, it doesn't support C99 syntax, so you can't declare variables in the midst of executable code. Either move all your declarations to the beginning pf the function, or force VS to compile the file as C++. To do the latter, either rename the file, or there is an option in file properties that allows you to do so.